# How to get a .NET CCW assembly to load configuration from a dll.config

Tags: .net, com-interop, configuration-files

I have a .NET component exposed as a **CCW** (Com Callable Wrapper) and being loaded into an unmanaged IIS application (ATL server).  The assembly is installed and registered with COM using `regasm /codebase`.

The component requires configuration such as is typically put into a Web.config file for an IIS app.  But I don't want to drop the config into either w3pw.exe.config or machine.config - Ideally I'd like the configuration to be installed live along side the assembly that is exposed to COM.

I haven't found a way to achieve this.  Since the COM assembly is loaded into the default AppDomain, so I don't think I can configure that domain to load from an alternate location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData ("APP_CONFIG_FILE",ConfigFile);
```

Where ConfigFile is the full path to your application's app.config file.(c:\test\myapp.config)  from [Load App.Config data into a DLL](http://thisoldcode.net/PermaLink,guid,3b28420f-7683-457f-8d2f-c29674bf4571.aspx)

Comment: I can't seem to make this work...I know this is an old question...but maybe someone will see this...